# Slow traceroute from GKE pod to GCE VPS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I've been troubleshooting issues with high latency on my GKE pods, and a `traceroute` yields results like the following when poking the database server for that cluster (which is a GCE VPS, but not part of the cluster):

```
$ traceroute -n -q5 -w30 10.164.0.2
traceroute to 10.164.0.2 (10.164.0.2), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.44.49.1  0.050 ms  0.011 ms  0.007 ms  0.008 ms  0.006 ms
 2  * 10.164.0.2  1.700 ms *  1.780 ms *
```

However, when I `traceroute` from the node itself (using `toolbox`, since the node is running COS), I get this (which makes sense):

```
$ traceroute -q5 -w30 10.164.0.2
traceroute to 10.164.0.2 (10.164.0.2), 64 hops max
  1   10.164.0.2  1.301ms  0.085ms  0.095ms  0.076ms  0.118ms
```

What could be/is causing the delays?

Note: I've observed this behaviour on multiple pods spread across different nodes, running both an ancient version of Debian and an up-to-date Alpine.

Comment: Some useful information you might be able to find [here](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/tutorials/optimize-app-latency).

Comment: Did you discover something about the issue?

Comment: If you have some concerns about network connectivity between Google Compute Engine VMs or between pods running on GKE and other GCE instances, you should rather report such issues on [Google's Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187180&template=1162717).